# boost::split: how to split a string with a character?

Tags: c++

I'm stuck with this simple problem.
Say I have a string which is consisted from characters [0-9]. What I would like to do is split the string by the single characters using boost::split.

```
std::string str = "0102725";
std::vector<std::string> str2;
boost::split(str2, str, boost::is_any_of(SOMETHING));
```

I'm looking for SOMETHING so that str2[0] contains "0", str2[1] contains "1", str2[2] contains "0" and so on. So far I have tried "", ':' and ":" but no luck...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::split` is overkill for that.

```
for (size_t i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
  str2.push_back(std::string(1, str.at(i)));
```

Comment: Which of `std::string`'s constructors do you think `str.at(i)`'s going to trigger...? ;-)

Comment: Sweet.  And +1 for a simple, practical approach.

Comment: @Mat Thanks! Looks like I was too obsessed with using boost::split.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from @Mat's approach, here is my take on it. Since you are separating characters you may not want,

```
vector<string> str2; // acquires character + extra space for '\0'
```

But rather,

```
vector<char> str2; // only single character
```

Here is how you can do it alternatively:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  str2.push_back(str[i]);
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/VxnVF). You can access `str2[i]` when you want.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach.